# Retrofit error: DB BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING (when I changed the server that hold Api)

Tags: android, json, xampp, retrofit

when I import my DB From a server to a localServer on my PC using XAMPP then I try to fetch data from DB using JSON Api and Retrofit I found that error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1 path $

I put the Api.php and DB.php files in C:\xampp\htdocs\file and I fill the DB details from PHPMyAdmin DB Server after I import It to PHPMyAdmin so I think it's alright. I think the error is in Api.php and My app It's Just a login Page in MainActivity.java.

Api.php

```
    <?php

include 'DB.php';
$db = DB::getInstance();
header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");

function UserLoginMethod($username , $password , $lat, $long){
    global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = ? AND  user_password = ?
             LIMIT 1";
    $user_info = $db->query($sql, [$username, $password]);


    CheckIsEmpty($user_info);
    //echo $db->getSQL();
    echo PrintJSON($user_info[0]);

}

switch (@$_GET['function']) {
    case "Login":
        UserLoginMethod(@$_GET['user_email'], @$_GET['user_password'], $_GET['user_location_latitude'], $_GET['user_location_longitude']);
        break;


}



function CheckIsEmpty($query) {
    if (is_null($query)||empty($query)){
        die (json_encode(array('error' => 'no items funded.'),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
    }
}
function PrintJSON($q){
    $j = json_encode($q);
    if (count($j) > 0 && !is_null($q) )
        return $j;
    else
        die (json_encode(array('error' => 'no items funded.'),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
}


function CreateDieError($body){
    die (json_encode(array("error" => $body),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
}

?>
```

ApiClient.java To connect to server

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.38/";
    public static final String PATH_URL = "/file/";//Path For Api

    static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null){

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

ApiInterface.java

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @Headers("Content-type: application/json")
    @GET(ApiClient.PATH_URL+"Api.php")
    Call<UserAccount> Login(@Query("function") String function, @Query("user_email") String email, @Query("user_password") String password,
                            @Query("user_location_latitude") Double Latitude,
                            @Query("user_location_longitude") Double Longitude);

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final Button loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        TextView signupTxt = findViewById(R.id.txtSignup);
        TextView forgetPassTxt = findViewById(R.id.txtForgetPassword);

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

            EditText emailEditeText = findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
            EditText passEditeText = findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

            UserLogin(apiInterface, emailEditeText, passEditeText);
        }
    });


 private void UserLogin(ApiInterface apiInterface, EditText emailEditeText, 
        EditText passEditeText){
        Call<UserAccount> call = apiInterface.Login("Login", emailEditeText.getText().toString(), Utility.md5(passEditeText.getText().toString()), Utility.myLocation.getLatitude(), Utility.myLocation.getLongitude());
            //make a call to server
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UserAccount>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserAccount> call, Response<UserAccount> response) {

                String errorBody = response.errorBody().toString();

                Log.d("Message", "code..."+response.code() + " message..." + response.message()+" body..."+errorBody);

                boolean check = response.isSuccessful();
                Log.i("log12", String.valueOf(check));
                String val = response.body().getError();
                Log.i("log1",val);
                if (val == null) {
                    prefManager.setLogin(true, response.body());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, " Login success" + response.body().getUsername(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }else {
                    if (response.body().getError().equals("no items funded.")){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "check Email and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response.body().getError(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("error", response.body().getError());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserAccount> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("login",t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

UserAccount.java

```
    public class UserAccount {

    private int userID;
    private String username;
    private String user_email;
    private String user_phone;
    private String user_password;
    private Double user_location_latitude;
    private Double user_location_longitude;

    private String error;

    // getter and setter  
}
```

any suggestions may be help. Thanks a lot

**Solution**: The problem is in Api exactly at count() function I change it to empty() function and it's work well.

Comment: does it works with remote server?

Answer (score 1):

change `PATH_URL = "/file/"` to `"file/"`

Comment: Same error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"

Comment: paste response string please

Comment: maybe json structure corrupted

Comment: I can't get response from  call.enqueue because it's move to onFailure not in onResponse

Comment: try with the web browser http://192.168.1.38/file/?function=aaa&user_email=ccc.....

Comment: delegate = {OkHttpCall@20768} 
message = "callback == null"
object = {LoginActivity$2@20772}  baseUrl = {HttpUrl@20792} "http://192.168.1.38/"
message = Cannot find local variable 'message'
httpMethod = "GET"
relativeUrl = "file/Api.php"
contentType = {MediaType@20795} "application/json"

Comment: It's return Index of /file

Comment: 192.168.1.38/file/Api.php?function=aaa&user_email=ccc&user_password=1234abc

Comment: Noting Just blank page.and i try to add user_location_latitude=0&user_location_longitude=0 nothing change

Comment: anyway UserLoginMethod should return at least "no items funded" object. Try to put some echo logs to switch-case

Comment: yes i try to do that and the output is  ** You come from Login <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\file\Api.php</b> on line <b>41</b><br />
{"error":"no items funded."}**

Comment: Finally I Found it the problem is in count() function  so I change it to !empty() and it's work well. I appreciate your help and thanks a lot @Nariman Have a good day.